# How to get the most date a text?

Tags: python

how to calculate the difference in date in a text file for each name and calculate his stay in day's and then return the most person with his stayed days for example

text file contain's

```
john 01/15 02/15
jason 01/11 01/15
john 02/10 02/12
```

output expected 
('john', 30 )

my code

```
def most_stayed_person(text):
    y=[]
    f = open(text, 'rt')
    for x in f:
        y.append(x.strip())

    return y
```

I failed to calculate the stayed days for every person in the text file 
can someone help me please

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import datetime
def most_stayed_person(text):
    y=[]
    f = open(text, 'rt')
    for x in f:
        name, date1, date2 = x.strip().split()
        diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%m/%y") - datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, "%m/%y")
        y.append((name, abs(diff.days)))
    f.close()
    return y
```

Read about datetime module here [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

if you only want most days stayed return:

```
import datetime
def most_stayed_person(text):
    y=[]
    f = open(text, 'rt')
    for x in f:
        name, date1, date2 = x.strip().split()
        diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%m/%y") - datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, "%m/%y")
        y.append(abs(diff.days))
    f.close()
    return max(y)
```

Comment: I'm getting the date with minus and I need the most days only returned

Comment: @jason i have returned, a list containing tuple wiht name and days stayed